# Shouldn't adapting the scree size of a fluid layout in the desktop show how the site should look for mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, screen-resolution

I'm a little bit confused about how fluid layouts, screen resolutions and how twitter bootstrap itself works.

I'm in the early ages of the the site mocking.

So what I have done so far looks reasonably well on the desktop.

[image]

When I resize the size of the window in chrome, the layout also adapts pretty well (though no perfect).

[image]

What confuses me is that when I browsed from an iPhone ad iPod touch, it just rendered a semi broken version of the big desktop rendering:

[image]

I know you can use media queries to affect the css of the those particular screens individually like this:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px){

}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 

}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

But shouldn't the iPhone show me the same thing I see when I reduce the window size manually in the desktop?

You can see a live version of the site [here](http://trufavarela.com/finnmount/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also define an initial viewport size for the mobile browser:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Read more at http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

Comment: that seems to do it! I'll read more about it... +1 obrigado! (I'll wait for some other answers and more info and then I'll probably accept thanks!)